# using zeromq in excel/vba

Tags: .net, excel, zeromq, vba

I am super new to zeromq and I am wondering if there's any example out there which uses zeromq in excel/vba?  I am guessing that we can use a C#/.net binding or VC++ and create a dll and have excel to call it?  I tried googling and did not find any example out there.  (I am an old C++ linux programming and have almost no idea about windows programming)

Any help in getting me started would be super useful.

Comment: What other, more general, tags can we add to this question to increase the audience?

Answer (score 0):

this might be interesting to you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140061%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite simple to use the .net binding for this. I'd suggest asking on the zeromq-dev mailing list or the #zeromq irc channel, where you'll get more eyeballs on this question.

Comment: You underestimate the number of eyeballs on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I added a .NET tag which will increase the number of knowledgeable eyeballs that look at this question. The solution might already exist in c#, for instance.